# Is setting the visibility redundant if the element is completely hidden by overflow?

Tags: javascript, html, css, performance

I'm developing a slide in/out panel using HTML and CSS.

I notice in some CSS code examples on the internet that they set the `visibility` property of the div to `hidden` once the div is completely out of view (via some negative `margin-left` index or some other), and obscured by `overflow: hidden` of its parent container. (and then back to visible when the user slides it out again)

However, in other examples they ignore this property, instead relying on the fact that it is completely hidden due to being out of view already.

I'm curious of the differences of these two approaches. One example I can think of is performance: I'm ignorant of whether or not browser rendering engines apply better optimizations to elements that are set to `visibility: hidden`, because it is guaranteed that they will not be seen.

Or is the browser smart enough to realize it is not being shown? Or does none of this matter, and the performance is identical regardless of whether it is visible to the user, hidden by overflow, or hidden by `visibility: hidden`?

Does anyone have any insight into this? Or can recommend the best practice?

Comment: How complex is the element that you're hiding? Unless it's huge, the performance difference is probably negligible.

Comment: It's rather complex, and I suppose performance is only part of the question. I'm also curious of the best practices regarding this design pattern.

Comment: I know that `display: none` will inhibit requests to dependent resources of replaced elements such as `<img>`, `<iframe>`, `<video>`, etc., but other than things like that I don't think there's much of a performance implication, and also not sure if that technique applies to `visibility: hidden` since that rule still allows the element to displace if it's anything besides `position: absolute` or `position: fixed`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was an interesting study done on this actually which can be found [here](http://taligarsiel.com/Projects/howbrowserswork1.htm#The_render_tree_relation_to_the_DOM_tree)

To save you reading it, I'd say this is the main bit you're probably after:

> The renderers correspond to the DOM elements, but the relation is not
>   one to one. Non visual DOM elements will not be inserted in the render
>   tree. An example is the "head" element. Also elements whose display
>   attribute was assigned to "none" will not appear in the tree (elements
>   with "hidden" visibility attribute will appear in the tree).

Basically saying, setting an element to have a `visibilty` of `none` will not stop it getting rendered but using `display: none` will.

In regards to the coding examples you spoke of, I'd say it's personal preference. Some people will set the `visibility` to `none` to maybe double-cover for themselves in the case that the hidden element gets put into view but doesnt need to show a particular element, maybe also to prevent the horizontal scroll bar from appearing too?

It's definitely not needed or required though and I'd personally leave the `visibility` property alone in this case.